# dynamically validation errors are not displaying and given json response correct

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

Parse error on line 4:

```
... required.<\/p>\n"}{    "error": "<p>T
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

for the below json response:

```
{
    "st": 0,
    "msg": "<p>The Title field is required.<\/p>\n<p>The Description field is required.<\/p>\n<p>The URL field is required.<\/p>\n<p>The Posted On field is required.<\/p>\n<p>The Expire Date field is required.<\/p>\n"
}{
    "error": "<p>The upload path does not appear to be valid.<\/p>"
}
```

Here is my controller file :

```
public function addnews()
{
        $userfile = 'userfile';

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'URL', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Image', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('postedon', 'Posted On', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('source', 'Source','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('expiredate', 'Expire Date', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        { 
            echo json_encode(array('st'=>0, 'msg' => validation_errors())); 
        }
        /******* extracting file extension ********/
        $org_filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($org_filename);
        //$file_extension = $path_parts['extension'];
        /***** end extracting file extension ******/

        $config['upload_path'] = './vadmin/uploads/news';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 1000;       
        //$config['file_name'] = 'news_'.time().'.'.$file_extension;

        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($_FILES);

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($userfile))
        {
           //echo '<br>entered into upload failed block.. ';
           $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
           echo json_encode($error);
        }

        else
        {
            /**** assignment of post data ******/
            $title = $this->input->post('title');
            $description = $this->input->post('description');
            $url = $this->input->post('url');
            $userfile = $this->input->post('userfile');
            $postedon = $this->input->post('postedon');     
            $source = $this->input->post('source');
            $expiredate = $this->input->post('expiredate');
            $status = $this->default_news_status ;
            /**** end assignment of post data ******/

            /**** load news model to insert reocrd into table *****/
            $this->load->model('vadmin/Newsmodel','',true);
            $this->Newsmodel->addRequestForm();
            /**** load news model to insert reocrd into table *****/

            //print jsone response for ajax request
            echo json_encode(array('st'=>1, 'msg' => 'Successfully Submitted'));

     }

}
```

Here is my view script:

```
function ajaxFileUpload()
{
    $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>vadmin/ajax/addnews/',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'userfile',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {title:$('#title').val(),description:$('#description').val(),url:$('#url').val(),userfile:$('#userfile').val(),postedon:$('#datepicker').val(),source:$('#source').val(),expiredate:$('#datepicker1').val()},
            /*beforeSend:function()
            {
                $("#loading").show();
            },
            complete:function()
            {
                $("#loading").hide();
            },  */          
            success: function (data)
            {
                 if(data.st == 0)
                {
                    $('#message').css('color','red');
                    $('#message').html(data.error).show(400);
                }
                if(data.st == 1)
                {
                    $('#message').css('color','green');
                    $('#message').html(data.msg).show(400);
                } 
                if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if(data.error != '')
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }else
                    {
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            },
            /*error: function (resp, status, e)
            {
                alert('ajax error :: '+e);
            }  */
        }
    );

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a comma in between the `}` and the `{`. This is happening because you're doing two separate `json_encode`s and `echo`ing them both.

Try something like this:

```
$response = array();

if($this->form_validation->run() === false) // note: triple ===
{ 
    $response['st'] = 0;
    $response['msg'] = validation_errors();
}
```

and below:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($userfile)) {
    $response['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else {
    // ..
    $response['st'] = 1;
    $response['msg'] = 'Successfully Submitted';
}
```

then at the bottom do a single `echo json_encode($response);`.

Comment: @user3496799 I don't understand what you mean. Does this not solve your problem? It should certainly fix the parse error.